# execute command over ssh connection

Tags: ssh, command-line, quoting

I want to excecute the following command over a ssh connection:

```
tmpValue=$(cat /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone8.pid) && top -b -U jboss -n 1 |grep $tmpValue |awk '{print $9}'
```

This command is working on my target machine.

Now I want to use this command from a different machine and execute it via ssh, so what I have done is this:

```
ssh jboss@myTargetServer tmpValue=$(cat /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone8.pid) && top -b -U jboss -n 1 |grep $tmpValue |awk '{print $9}'
```

The result is

```
 cat: /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone8.pid: No such file or directory
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Whats wrong with my call?

Comment: shure, as I said before. If I execute the command directly on the target machine, everything is fine.

Comment: `top` is an interactive full-screen process monitor.  `ps` is a command-line tool to display info about processes.  Why do people use `top` when they should be using `ps`? Yes, `top` has a batch mode.  it's crappy for the purpose it's supposed to fulfil....use the right tool for the job.   e.g. `ps -U jboss -u jboss -o pid,pcpu` to get the PID and %CPU from all processes with uid or euid of  'jboss'.  or `ps h --pid  12345 -o pcpu` to get %CPU from pid 12345.

Comment: Thx, always want to learn new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to simplify the command so that you have fewer special characters on which the shell might choke:

```
ssh jboss@myTargetServer 'ps -p $(cat /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone8.pid) -o %cpu= 2>/dev/null'
```

The trailing `2>/dev/null` throws away the error text in the event that the PID file either cannot be found or contains a stale PID.

Comment: Thx, this is working. I think I will use it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting those commands into a script that you remotely call with `ssh`. Otherwise you'd need to put the whole "remote" part of the command line into quotes and properly escape everything inside. This can be tedious and error prone. That's why remote script call.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I would like to do this on several target systems. It would be a lot of maintenance work if I have to place a shell script everywhere.

Comment: Well, put quotes on it hence. )

Answer (score 1):

The second command as you have it runs the code part (`$()`) in local subshell. You need to make it run on the other side by escaping special characters (basically `$`):

```
ssh jboss@myTargetServer tmpValue=\$(cat /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone8.pid) \
 && top -b -U jboss -n 1 |grep \$tmpValue |awk '{print $9}'
```

or put it all into the apostrophes `'` and escape the inner ones:

```
ssh jboss@myTargetServer 'tmpValue=$(cat /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone8.pid) \
 && top -b -U jboss -n 1 |grep \$tmpValue |awk \'{print $9}\''
```

I didn't test it, but it is the basic idea what should be done to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really reluctant about writing scripts you may find
[Here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) handy. Short said, you add `<< SOMETEXMARKER` to the end of the line and continue entering as many commands for remote host as you like.
Then, on the last line you enter (at the very beginning of the line)
the same `SOMETEXTMARKER` and that makes the entered commands get executed remotely

Here's a sample

```
[bobby@bobby ~]$ ssh jimmy@jimmy << MRK '
> # single quote above makes all vars resolve on remote host
> echo remote user and host are : 
> echo $USER $(hostname)
> # entereing closing single quote
> '
> # finally entereing the marker
> MRK
remote user and host are :
jimmy jimmy
```